# Sending form data as table formatted email in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, html-table

I am using below code to send a PHP form data as email. For some strange reason i get the email only for 6 fields, anything more than that i don't receive the email.

Can someone please point out what am i doing wrong ?

i am using `$email` in mail function for now to just test rather than doing with actual email.

```php
<?php

  if(!empty($_POST["emailid"])) {
     $name = $_POST["firstname"];
     $middle = $_POST["middlename"];
     $lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
     $dob = $_POST["dob"];
     $mobile = $_POST["mobileno"];
     $whatsapp = $_POST["Whatsapp"];
     $company = $_POST["companyname"];
     $gender = $_POST["gendertype"];
     $country = $_POST["country"];
     $city = $_POST["city"];
     $address = $_POST["address"];
     $pincode = $_POST["post"];
     $id = $_POST["idnumber"];
     $adult = $_POST["adult"];
     $children = $_POST["children"];
     $roomtype = $_POST["roomtype"];
     $in = $_POST["arrivate"];
     $out = $_POST["tentative"];
     $location = $_POST["location"];
     $worklocation = $_POST["worklocation"];
     $pickup = $_POST["pickup"];
     $flight = $_POST["FlightNo"];
     $intime = $_POST["ATime"];
     $email = $_POST["emailid"];
     $subject ="Reservations - New Booking ".$_POST["emailid"];
     $toEmail = $_POST["emailid"];
     //$mailHeaders = "From: " . $name . "<". $email .">\r\n";


     $message = "New Booking: Please find the applicant's details to process further" ;
     $message.='<br>';
    $message .="<table style='font-family: Arial;'><tbody><tr><td style='background: #eee; padding: 10px;'>First Name :</td><td style='background: #fda; padding: 10px;'>$name</td></tr>";
    $message .="<tr><td style='background: #eee; padding: 10px;'>Middle Name :</td><td style='background: #fda; padding: 10px;'>$middle</td></tr>";
    $message .="<tr><td style='background: #eee; padding: 10px;'>Last Name :</td><td style='background: #fda; padding: 10px;'>$lastname</td></tr>";
    $message .="<tr><td style='background: #eee; padding: 10px;'>Date of Birth :</td><td style='background: #fda; padding: 10px;'>$dob</td></tr>";
    $message .="<tr><td style='background: #eee; padding: 10px;'>Mobile :</td><td style='background: #fda; padding: 10px;'>$mobile</td></tr>";
    $message .="<tr><td style='background: #eee; padding: 10px;'>Whats App :</td><td style='background: #fda; padding: 10px;'>$whatsapp</td></tr>";
    //$message .="<tr><td style='background: #eee; padding: 10px;'>Email :</td><td style='background: #fda; padding: 10px;'>$email</td></tr>";
   // $message .="<tr><td style='background: #eee; padding: 10px;'>Company Name :</td><td style='background: #fda; padding: 10px;'>$company</td></tr>";
   // $message .="<tr><td style='background: #eee; padding: 10px;'>Gender :</td><td style='background: #fda; padding: 10px;'>$gender</td></tr>";
   // $message .="<tr><td style='background: #eee; padding: 10px;'>Country :</td><td style='background: #fda; padding: 10px;'>$country</td></tr>";
   // $message .="<tr><td style='background: #eee; padding: 10px;'>City :</td><td style='background: #fda; padding: 10px;'>$city</td></tr>";
  //  $message .="<tr><td style='background: #eee; padding: 10px;'>Address :</td><td style='background: #fda; padding: 10px;'>$address</td></tr>";
  //  $message .="<tr><td style='background: #eee; padding: 10px;'>Zip Code :</td><td style='background: #fda; padding: 10px;'>$pincode</td></tr>";
  //  $message .="<tr><td style='background: #eee; padding: 10px;'>ID Number :</td><td style='background: #fda; padding: 10px;'>$id</td></tr>";
//  $message .="<tr><td style='background: #eee; padding: 10px;'>No. of Adults :</td><td style='background: #fda; padding: 10px;'>$adult</td></tr>";
//  $message .="<tr><td style='background: #eee; padding: 10px;'>No. of Children :</td><td style='background: #fda; padding: 10px;'>$children</td></tr>";
   // $message .="<tr><td style='background: #eee; padding: 10px;'>Room Type :</td><td style='background: #fda; padding: 10px;'>$roomtype</td></tr>";
  //  $message .="<tr><td style='background: #eee; padding: 10px;'>Check In :</td><td style='background: #fda; padding: 10px;'>$in</td></tr>";
  //  $message .="<tr><td style='background: #eee; padding: 10px;'>Check out :</td><td style='background: #fda; padding: 10px;'>$out</td></tr>";
    $message .="<tr><td style='background: #eee; padding: 10px;'>Preferred Location :</td><td style='background: #fda; padding: 10px;'>$location</td></tr>";
//    $message .="<tr><td style='background: #eee; padding: 10px;'>Work Location :</td><td style='background: #fda; padding: 10px;'>$worklocation</td></tr>";
//  $message .="<tr><td style='background: #eee; padding: 10px;'>Airport Pickup :</td><td style='background: #fda; padding: 10px;'>$pickup</td></tr>";
//  $message .="<tr><td style='background: #eee; padding: 10px;'>Flight Number :</td><td style='background: #fda; padding: 10px;'>$flight</td></tr>";
    $message .="<tr><td style='background: #eee; padding: 10px;'>Arrival Time :</td><td style='background: #fda; padding: 10px;'>$intime</td></tr></tbody></table>";


    //$message .="Thank You"';

    $header = "From:Reservations@domain.com \r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


    mail($email, $subject, $message, $header);
    //$messages ='Thanks for contacting us. We have received your details , will get back to you soon.';
    //mail($toEmail, $subject, $messages, $header);
```

Comment: Are you sure the form input names all correspond to the POST data? Which of the fields are missing and which ones did you get?

Comment: if i keep it simple, and not format the table around it, then i get all the fields. It seems to be random in case of the fields, i tried with few different fields thats why all the commented out lines, like :
First Name : Priya
Middle Name : 
Last Name : dfnhhg
Date of Birth : 1990-01-01
Preferred Location : Utrecht
Arrival Time :

OR

First Name : Priya
Middle Name : 
Last Name : dfnhhg
Date of Birth : 1990-01-01
Mobile : 111111111
Arrival Time :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mail() function no longer works properly! try some other library like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: he is getting mail but only six values not all values. This is not relevant

Comment: I know, that kinda problem will occur in mail() function, using **phpmailer** is the only way out there!

Comment: if i keep it simple, and not format the table around it, then i get all the fields.

Comment: ok, i changed it to use phpmailer and it does work. Thank you. Not sure whats the issue with mail function.

Comment: I'm tired find out what's the problem with mail() function. in the beginning, if I add a '.' symbol in the mail id it won't work, I don't even know what was the logic behind. so I started using phpmailer as everyone does. @BeenaDagar